# How can I debug with xdebug PHP SPL Properties?

Tags: php, xdebug

My situation:

```
(php 7.4 and phpstorm 2021.3 on macosx m1)
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.1.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2021, by Derick Rethans
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.27, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

My problem:

[image]

Comment: So what 1) your PHP version is; 2) PhpStorm (or is it IntelliJ IDEA) version; 3) where exactly that comes from (Watches panel; Evaluate window; variables panel)? 4) Some simple code sample to reproduce the issue.

Comment: php 7.4 and phpstorm 2021.3

Comment: Any code sample? Where this happens (which tool/panel)? There was an issue with PHP 8.1 and Watches/Evaluate window (due to the way how IDE uses that + change in how `$GLOBALS` is handled in PHP 8.1) but it's not your case. Need a code to test it.

Comment: This could well be a bug, or simply no support for SplPriorityQueues yet. Please provide a short reproducible script (as per https://xdebug.org/reporting-bugs) and send it to Xdebug's bug tracker (https://bugs.xdebug.org) and I can have a look.